# Python when generator 'yield' encounter 'random'

Tags: python, random, generator

Here i want to generate 5 dicts, where 'a' is index 'i', 'b' is a random int between 0 and 5. But result stuck at 'a'=0, it kept generate new c from random.randint(0,5) and 'i' remained the same. how to fix this? thx a lot

```
def wdg():
    for i in range(5):
        c = random.randint(0,5)
        yield {'a':i,'b':c}

next(wdg())
```

Comment: Can you please be specific about the problem you are encountering?

Comment: If you do `next(wdg())` over and over you're gonna create a new generator object every time. Instead assign it to something (`gen = wdg()`), and then do `next(gen)`.

Comment: Your program is terminating after the first `yield`. To get all of the values a generator is capable of generating, you have to iterate over it. `for result in wdg(): print (result)`

Comment: thx a lot,  (gen = wdg()), and then do next(gen) can do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign generator to a variable for example 'generator'. Then each time you call next(generator) one execution will occur, leading to increment i by one and generate random c:

```
generator = wdg()
print(next(generator))
```

Comment: thx a lot, this did a great job